# Replace function in Excel does not work anymore after moving a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I have a problem with the code below.
What I am trying to do is let a user type in a range of cells, which he puts in something. This will always be in column A of my sheet. Then I specify these inputs as startmyRange and endnewRange. I also create the variables startnewRange and endnewRange, which are the same cells in column B by replacing A from the users inputs with B. The code is activated by clicking a button on my excel sheet. But after I moved around my excel sheet and renamed it, suddenly my code did not work anymore. I added the MsgBox commands and found out that by some reason the 'A's from the users input are not replaced by 'B's anymore. Does anyone have an idea why the replace function does not work anymore. Thank you already in advance for any suggestions.

I just started coding in VBA a few weeks ago and this is the first time I am using this forum. So if anything in my question is described in a rather confusing way or there is any important information missing my apologies for that and please do not hesitate to ask!

```
Public Sub rewrite_eurogentec_universal()
    Range("c3", "d1048576").Clear
    Range("b2", "b1048576").Clear
    'Dim startmyRange, endmyRange, startnewRange, endnewRange As String
    startmyRange = InputBox("With which cell start does your list of oligos start?")
    endmyRange = InputBox("With which cell start does your list of oligos end?")
    startnewRange = Replace(startmyRange, "A", "B")
    startnewRange = Replace(startmyRange, "a", "B")
    endnewRange = Replace(endmyRange, "A", "B")
    endnewRange = Replace(endmyRange, "a", "B")
    MsgBox (startmyRange & " " & endmyRange)
    MsgBox (startnewRange & " " & endnewRange)
    Range(startnewRange, endnewRange).Value = Range(startmyRange, endmyRange).Value
    MsgBox (startmyRange & " " & endmyRange)
    MsgBox (startnewRange & " " & endnewRange)
    Call DNA_eurogentec_universal(Range(startnewRange, endnewRange))
    Call RNA_eurogentec_universal("(", ")", "r", Range(startnewRange, endnewRange)) 
    Call RNA_eurogentec_universal("[", "]", "m", Range(startnewRange, endnewRange))
    Call RNA_eurogentec_universal("{", "}", "l", Range(startnewRange, endnewRange))
    Call eurogentec_universal_s_o(Range(startnewRange, endnewRange))
    Range("C2:D2").Select
    endnewRange = Replace(endnewRange, "B", "D")
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2", endnewRange), Type:=xlFillDefault
    ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier for the user just to enter the start and end row numbers ?

Comment: ...or have your user select the list of oligos before running the macro, then just grab the selection.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, indeed these two alternatives should also work. However, I still do not understand why the script I wrote goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The code does not work (if the input is "A") because the second lowercase `replace` sets the `startnewrange` back to the original value.

```
startnewRange = Replace(startmyRange, "A", "B")
startnewRange = Replace(startmyRange, "a", "B")
```

The correction is to the capitalise the input and use one replace

```
startnewRange = Replace(UCase(startmyRange), "A", "B")
```

Comment: What a stupid mistake indeed and I didn't see it all the time. Thank you so much for this simple solution!!